# Why does this code work on Desktop but not Android?

Tags: android, c, sockets, sdl, sdl-2

I have been trying to modify this SDL2 [game](https://github.com/mcksp/sdl-game) source code to make it playable on android devices.

I had a problem and it was that when I run the game as a host all players are frozen in place and doesn't move

I tracked the problem down until I got to this function

this thread loop is supposed to run forever but it runs only once or twice when I run the app

```
void *client_loop(void *arg) {
    int socket = *((int *) arg);
    int16_t tab[BUF_MAX];
    int length;
    int id, bullets_in_array;
    while (1) {
        length = client_listen(socket, tab);
        id = tab[0];
        if (id == -1) {
            receive_new_id(tab[1]);
        }
            SDL_Log("I'm called %i", id);
        if (id >= 0) {
            check_if_its_new_player(id);
            players[id].position.x = tab[1];
            players[id].position.y = tab[2];
            players[id].kills = tab[3];
            players[id].deaths = tab[4];
        }
        if (id == -2) {
            bullets_in_array = (length - sizeof(int16_t)) / (sizeof(int16_t) * 2);
            memcpy(bullets_client, tab + 1, sizeof(int16_t) * 2 * bullets_in_array);
            bullets_number = bullets_in_array;
        }
        usleep(50);
    }
}
```

[image: Logcat]

this causes the game to not update players positions.
I think that the `client_listen(socket, tab)` might be suspicious here it is

```
int client_listen(int sock, int16_t *tab){
    int length = recvfrom(sock, tab, sizeof(int16_t) * BUF_MAX, 0, NULL, 0);
    return length;
}
```

I think this logcat might be related to the problem it appears after few seconds when run the app[image: Logcat]

the same code works on desktop as you can see the client_loop runs forever on DESKTOP[image: Game on desktop].

I use `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>` in the manifest file

Comment: What is function `client_listen(...)`?

Comment: It receives the data from the server in the case of you being the game host it's supposed to receive data from your socket using the UDP protocol.

Comment: It worked when I built it with the release option.
which is still weird. why don't it work when I build it as debug ?